# Find first index of matching character from two strings using parallel streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Trying to figure out whether it is possible to find what the first index of a matching character that is within one string that is also in another string. So for example:

```
String first = "test";
String second = "123er";
int value = get(test, other);
// method would return 1, as the first matching character in 
// 123er, e is at index 1 of test
```

So I'm trying to accomplish this using parallel streams. I know I can find whether there is a matching character fairly simply like such:

```
test.chars().parallel().anyMatch(other::contains);
```

How would I use this to find the exact index?

Comment: But `e` is at index `1`, and `t` is also in `other`, so it should return `0`, right?

Comment: And I am  wondering how much of a performance hit using parallel streams will introduce here. In other words: why the parallel?

Comment: @GhostCat, I would be lead to believe that by checking each character in parallel, the complexity would be reduced to that of what the first string is being checked against. It's a question of having a starting point, and once I reach larger texts being able to apply this.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the result. Should it be 1, not because `e` is at index 1 of `test`, but because `t` is at index 1 of `other` and the first matching character of `test` in `other` is `t`? That is assuming we're reading from left to right, but from right to left, it would be the same.

Comment: @Tunaki, I could make a clearer example. If it were to be get("one","ThisIs-n"); the answer would be 1. If it were get("ThisIs-n","one") it would be 7.

Comment: I suggest editing your question with the clearer example, because the answers you currently have are not answering that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really care for performance, you should try to avoid the `O(n × m)` time complexity of iterating over one string for every character of the other. So, first iterate over one string to get a data structure supporting efficient (`O(1)`) lookup, then iterate over the other utilizing this.

```
BitSet encountered = new BitSet();
test.chars().forEach(encountered::set);
int index = IntStream.range(0, other.length())
    .filter(ix->encountered.get(other.charAt(ix)))
    .findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

If the strings are sufficiently large, the `O(n + m)` time complexity of this solution will turn to much shorter execution times. For smaller strings, it’s irrelevant anyway.

If you really think, the strings are large enough to benefit from parallel processing (which is very unlikely), you can perform both operations in parallel, with small adaptions:

```
BitSet encountered = CharBuffer.wrap(test).chars().parallel()
    .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or);
int index = IntStream.range(0, other.length()).parallel()
    .filter(ix -> encountered.get(other.charAt(ix)))
    .findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

The first operation uses the slightly more complicated, parallel compatible `collect` now and it contains a not-so-obvious change for the Stream creation.

The problem is described in [bug report JDK-8071477](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071477). Simply said, the stream returned by `String.chars()` has a poor splitting capability, hence a poor parallel performance. The code above wraps the string in a `CharBuffer`, whose `chars()` method returns a different implementation, having the same semantics, but a good parallel performance. This work-around should become obsolete with Java 9.

Alternatively, you could use `IntStream.range(0, test.length()).map(test::charAt)` to create a stream with a good parallel performance. The second operation already works that way.

But, as said, for this specific task it’s rather unlikely that you ever encounter strings large enough to make parallel processing beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by relying on [`String#indexOf(int ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-), keeping only `values >= 0` to remove non existing characters then get the first value.

```
// Get the index of each characters of test in other
// Keep only the positive values
// Then return the first match
// Or -1 if we have no match
int result = test.chars()
    .parallel()
    .map(other::indexOf)
    .filter(i -> i >= 0)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(-1);
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

**NB 1:** The result is `1` not `2` because indexes start from `0` not `1`.

**NB 2:** Unless you have very very long `String`, using a **parallel** `Stream` in this case should not help much in term of performances because the tasks are not complexes and creating, starting and synchronizing threads has a very high cost so you will probably get your result much slower than with a normal stream.

Comment: I have no idea whether this really works. But I trust you ... nice new avatar icon by the way.

Comment: This solution is actually brilliant :D one note: min() is a overkill because enforces processing of a whole stream. findFirst() would be probably a better choice

Comment: @pivovarit Well, at least for the given example, I think the **overkill** starts already with the idea of calling *parallel()* here.

Comment: Although the 1 returned has nothing to do with the `e` being at index 1 of `test`, as the question suggests, but the `t` being as index 1 of `other`.

Comment: @GhostCat: …and it still bears the sequential `indexOf` operation. Further, there is an implementation specific problem making a fast parallel execution even less likely (unless you know how to work-around), as described in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40677618/2711488).

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Nicolas' answer here. `min()` method enforces consumption of the whole `Stream`. In such cases, it's better to use `findFirst()` which stops the whole execution after finding the first matching element and not the minimum of all:

```
test.chars().parallel()
  .map(other::indexOf)
  .filter(i -> i >= 0)
  .findFirst()
  .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```